# How many exercises in/from this book

Tags: prepositions

> How many exercises **in this book** have you done? Some of them.

Does "in this book" means here that they do their exercises directly in that book, right? So, it's possible to ask "How many exercises from this book have you done?" if you do them in your notebook. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it your sentence? It seems odd.
I would expect "How many exercises have you done in this book?", and I don't think it would imply writing directly in the book.

Even more likely would be "How many of the exercises in this book have you done?", again without meaning directly written in the book.

Whether the exercises are done by writing in a book (such as a workbook) would depend on whether the book is made for that use or not. I don't think that difference would be reflected in a question about how many of them have been done.

Comment: that sentence is from my grammar book.

Comment: As I understood from your answer "How many exercises from this book..." is not used in English. Right?

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't be used; it just seems less likely than the word order I suggested.

Comment: "How many exercises from this book have you done" is valid, and reads pretty naturally. As Jack says, adding of, as in "How many of the exercises in this book have you done?" reads quite naturally, and removes the ambiguity about the meaning of the word "in" (It is clear in that formation that you are talking about "exercises in the book"